# Distance between IOS section and section

Tags: ios, objective-c

static cell  style:grouped
[image]

[image]

There is always a gap between the group and the navigation bar（I use red mark in the picture）

None of the following methods work：
[image]

Is there any way to cancel the spacing between the group and the navigation bar, and set the direct spacing between the group and the group to 0 ?

Comment: Did you tried to set value to something small like 0.1 or 1 instead of 0 ?

Comment: amazing!!!I tried various methods for one day, and you solved my problem in one sentence！！！thanks very very very very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the direct distance between the group and the navigation bar, like this:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, CGFLOAT_MIN)];
```

According to the help of netizens, I understand that I only need to set the height of the header and footer to 0.1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

This behavior was introduced in iOS 15: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10059?time=438
The added [`sectionHeaderTopPadding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/3750914-sectionheadertoppadding) can be removed (at least for `plain` tables) by setting:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = CGFloat(0)
}

// Or for a specific table:
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = .leastNormalMagnitude  // if 0 doesn't work
}
```