# Weird Gap in iOS UITableView Cells in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[Gap in UITableView Cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v0Aj.jpg)

I have added a UITableViewController through code but in iOS and it works okay in iOS 14 but in iOS 15 it shows a weird gap between cells.

I have tried everything that is adding HeaderView, FooterView, two new properties that is introduced in iOS 15

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
   tableView.fillerRowHeight = 0.0
   tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
        
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     return UIView()
}
        
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     return UIView()
}
```

But unfortunately nothing works and the weird gap appears in iOS 15 UITableView.

Comment: Use a small value like 0.1 or CGFLOAT_MIN for footer and header.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distance between IOS section and section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72701980/distance-between-ios-section-and-section)

Comment: Tried but it's not working. The gap still persists in iOS 15 only.

Comment: No, it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you mean a gap between *sections*, not cells? What UITableViewStyle are you using? It does seem like you're experiencing this new padding behavior: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10059?time=438 but `sectionHeaderTopPadding` appears to only apply to `.plain`...